# fit_generator is still loading everything into memory

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to train a cnn lstm on 720p video. Each video is 100 frames and I believe the resolution is necessary for what I need this application to do. I'm using a generator to train on but it tries to load everything into memory and then doesn't train. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what is going on.

```
2019-08-21 17:27:26.322181: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7335
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 8.00GiB freeMemory: 6.61GiB
2019-08-21 17:27:26.326940: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-08-21 17:27:26.811347: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-08-21 17:27:26.814274: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0
2019-08-21 17:27:26.815961: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N
2019-08-21 17:27:26.817783: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow 
device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6362 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2019-08-21 17:27:27.195352: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:124] 
Allocation of 30198988800 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

This is the main issue I am running into. I tried changing my generator to look like many other examples online but none of them seem to work. I Tried changing my model size to see if maybe the model was to large to load into memory but the same error comes up every time. I've tried changing the batch size in generator function but same the problem comes up.

My generator class looks like this:

```
class Generator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, available_ids,labels, batch_size=1, dim= 
(100,720,1280,3), n_channels=1, n_classes=38, shuffle=True):
    self.available_ids = available_ids
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.dim = dim
    self.labels = labels
    self.n_channels = n_channels
    self.n_classes = n_classes
    self.shuffle= shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()

def on_epoch_end(self):
    self.indexs = np.arange(start=1, stop=len(self.available_ids)+1)
    if self.shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexs)


def __len__(self):
    return int(len(self.available_ids)/self.batch_size)

def __data_gen(self, batch_ids):

    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim))
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

    for i, ID in enumerate(batch_ids):
        X[i,] = np.load('train_data/train_vid_{}.npy'.format(ID))
        y[i] = self.labels[ID-1]

    print(X.shape)

    return X, to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)

def __getitem__(self, start):
        indexes = self.indexs[(start*self.batch_size):((start+1)*self.batch_size)]

        X, y = self.__data_gen(indexes)

        return X,y
```

I based it on the code from here https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

The model and the rest of the code:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same'), input_shape= 
(100,720,1280,3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2))))
#model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same')))
#model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))
#model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
#model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same')))
#model.add(TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization()))
#model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
#model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=(2,2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(38, activation='softmax'))


train_gen = Generator(available_ids=train_ids, labels=train_labels)
val_gen = Generator(available_ids=val_ids, labels=val_labels)


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4), metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, steps_per_epoch=len(train_ids), validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps = len(val_ids), epochs=100, verbose=0)
```

I've been searching around for the right way to do this for at least a week. The other post on this does not really answer my question. If someone could please help me with this that would be great.

Comment: Here's a little update to what I've been trying to do. I transferred all the code onto a google colab notebook since that has superior computing power. I have resized the videos down to 3/4 it's original size to try and save some memory. When I run it on google colab the machine runs out of memory. I'm still confused on what generators are supposed to do. I was under the impression that they load one batch at a time and delete the previous one from memory. This clearly isn't the case since the ram usage keeps going up and not staying the same.